# Is it suspicious or odd to stand by the gate of a GA airport watching the planes?

Tags: general-aviation, airport, security, plane-spotting

Would it be likely to be seen as odd or suspicious for someone who is not a pilot to stand outside the fence around a GA airport in the US watching the aircraft?

Comment: If you're lucky sometime will show you around and/or let you hang out for a flight.

Comment: @tedder42  I agree, that's the way it works in the UK, dunno about the US.  But I just remembered that a bunch of plane spotters were charged with spying in Greece a while back at a military base:  http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/hi/dates/stories/november/12/newsid_2518000/2518385.stm   Also, I was prevented from taking photos at a small (commercal) regional airport in India a couple of years ago...

Comment: Not related to your question about the US, but a lot of countries have shared commercial and military airports and that kind of activity would probably draw unwanted attention from the authorities.

Comment: Binoculars may make you look less suspicious.

Comment: Jus watch on Big Jet TV on youtube https://www.youtube.com/c/BigJetTV?app=desktop https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-60434909

Comment: @DaveGremlin Those idiots were actually on the premises of the airbase, and trying to hide from security. Never a good idea.

Comment: "Suspicious" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @jwenting Also, there's a BIG difference between a military base and a GA airport.  You'd get a similar reaction hanging around at any military base, regardless of whether it had an airstrip.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman true, but usually if you just hang out outside the airbase perimeter you're left alone, you'll at most be watched from a patrol car or other security staff. These guys in Greece had breached the airbase perimeter and were walking on the grounds, knowingly, then fled when approached by guards.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I mainly fly in the UK and Europe, however I trained in the US and have flown there a few times since. I have probably 50 hours in total in the US.

I can tell you that almost without fail, every airfield I have ever flown from anywhere in the world has always had some level of plane spotting activity. It is a hugely popular pastime with both photographers and people who just like watching.

I don't think there's anything particularly suspicious about it, so long as you're not trespassing, not touching anything you shouldn't be, and not causing any interferrence.

Answer (score 33):

It depends on how you go about it.

Don't wear all black or camo with a face mask.  Don't sneak around in the grass, or run from building to building seeking cover.

Plane spotting is a somewhat common hobby -- you might check out some plane spotting forums for tips on not getting hassled.  You might think having a camera with a lens as long as your arm would be suspicious...  yeah, it is still suspicious.

Many GA airports have a restaurant or a designated viewing area.  My local small airport (KSBP) has both of these.  It also has a picnic table along a back road near mid field at a particularly good vantage point.  At the other end of the field, there is a wide spot in the road directly under the ILS approach path that people frequently use.

You should be able to find some contact information for an airport -- either a local airport authority, an FBO, or some other on airport business.  Give them a call, they can probably tell you the best vantage point.

Of course, the best place to watch planes on approach at my airport is from one of the wineries under the approach path.  Tolosa has a lovely garden with some seating areas.  You can take your tasting outside and watch airplanes land from a couch.  I realize that is not a solution that works for everybody, but it is good if you can get it.

Comment: There is no restaurant or anything like that at this airport. The only "businesses" are the local office for an air ambulance company, and the flying club's self service fuel station, which is behind the gate. There are parking areas on both sides of the fence; it's probably fine to park in the outside parking area and watch from there? And maybe walk around in the parking area? Any photography would be with a phone.

Comment: Any of those sound great.  Realize that people who work at an airport are likely airplane people -- they love watching airplanes too.  Call up the flying club and they'll tell you the best places to watch from.  I was joking about the camera, plane spotters have a stereotype of wearing a camera vest with lots of equipment and several huge lenses.  Use whatever you'e got.  Have a great time!

Comment: And if you just came from the hardware store where you bought a 4' section of black 3" PVC pipe, leave it in the car.  Don't watch planes with it across one shoulder.

Comment: Agreed. Asking the people in the flying club with both likely get you good advice for the specific airport you have in mind and also will make your intentions known to them. As long as the airport involved isn't something like Edwards AFB or Groom Lake, the local pilots are generally going to be understanding and friendly to people who stand around and watch planes because they probably do that, too. :)

Comment: @RobMcDonald I've got a 400mm zoom lens on my camera... not quite as long as my arm but it does stick out a bit at the tightest zoom.  I'm not near an airport though, I take pictures of plane and helicopters mostly that fly over my house.  It's always fun the take pictures of *police helicopters* because I can see which way *their* camera is pointing when I zoom in on the resulting picture.

Comment: @MichaelHall Yes yes, that gets filed in the same category as "Don't put candles wrapped around an alarm clock or a bowling ball with a rope sticking out of it in your luggage"

Comment: This might sound silly, but I have a fluorescent yellow vest. Should I wear it?

Comment: @Someone That would be sensible if you're going somewhere that ground traffic will be passing near you, e.g., you might have to cross roads to get to a good plane spotting location and you might be distracted by a plane when you should be looking out for cars.

Comment: @Someone Yes, and carry a clipboard with you too... that should get you anywhere.

Comment: @Michael I don't get it; why the clipboard? Do FAA inspectors wear yellow vests and carry clipboards or something?

Comment: @Someone The clipboard thing is a joke: if you look official with a high-vis vest and a clipboard, then people will assume you are allowed to be there. I suspect you would need a hard hat and new-looking steel toe-cap boots to complete the outfit.

Comment: Clipboard used to be the standard go-anywhere solution. For better or worse, it doesn't work as well any more. But I have a very brightly colored jacket that I got for free (another story...) and I wear just because I have it (comfortable, warm enough for spring/fall weather). Wearing that jacket I have been mistaken for road/construction workers...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Modern replacement for a clipboard would just be an iPad or equivalent tablet.  Preferably one with a ruggedized protective casing around it so it looks like you bring this to worksites on a regular basis.

Comment: @Someone, A yellow vest might not be the best idea, it could be perceived as trying to impersonate authorized personnel if that's what they wear.

Answer (score 4):

Being from Arizona, the only major airports I know of are Gateway and Sky Harbor. Both of which have plenty of plane watchers. As a previous answer has stated, don't touch anything, don't be sneaking around, and don't suddenly dart away as soon as you are seen, as people may think you're planning to hijack a plane, escape security, or commit a crime. Try not to wear all back or camouflage clothing, especially if you do happen to be sneaking around, darting off, and touching stuff, as that will make you even more suspicious. Other than that, most people aren't suspicious of plane watchers.

EDIT: As for GA airports: the only one I know of is in Iowa and I barely remember going there (I was about 2 or 3 at the time) but according to my father, the fences surrounding the airport were lined with plane watchers so I'd think from that information it's totally fine.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Aviation.SE! Not sure if you're familiar with the term or not, but the "GA" that the question is referring to means "general aviation," which is more-or-less FAA-speak for "not commercial or military." When people talk about "GA airports," they normally mean small regional airports used mostly or exclusively by private individuals or companies for their light aircraft or business jets, so generally airports that are much, much smaller than Sky Harbor with no passenger terminal. Generally something more like the Sedona airport.

Comment: and oh, stay outside the airfield boundaries unless the spot is a clearly marked dedicated spotting area, and don't even touch the perimeter fence.